# Display only time on axis with matplotlib.plot_dates

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time

So I've spent some time managing to plot data using time on the x-axis, and the way I've found to do that is to use matplotlib.plot_date after converting datetime objects to pltdates objects.

```
X_d = pltdates.date2num(X) # X is an array containing datetime objects
(...)
plt.plot_date(X_d, Y)
```

It works great, all my data is plotted properly.

[Plot with dates appearing on x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fEds.png)

However, all the measures I want to plot were made the same day (17/12/2021), the only difference is the time.

As shown on the image, matplotlib still displays the number of the the day (17th) although it is the same within the whole plot.

Anyone has a clue how to keep only the time, still using matplotlib.plot_date?

Comment: You might try `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))`.  See also [this old tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it actually solved my problem!!
The page you sent me a link to is pretty interesting, I might take a deeper look in the future if I spend more time making graphs on Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

origin = ['2020-02-05 04:11:55',
          '2020-02-05 05:01:51',
          '2020-02-05 07:44:49']

a = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in origin]
b = ['35.764299', '20.3008', '36.94704']
x = matplotlib.dates.date2num(a)

formatter = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.setp(axes.get_xticklabels(), rotation=15)

axes.plot(x, b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This effectively allows to display the time only, but then I don't have the automatic setting of the x ticks (16:00, 16:10, etc.) and get quite random values under the axis (16:11, 16:27 and so on), and I do not want to do set this manually. JohanC's solution above provides just what I wanted. Thanks anyway!